# Python Typeerror on Windows Machine but works fine on virtual compilers

Tags: python, tuples, typeerror, combinations

**This code snippet runs fine on the online compiler but throws an error on my windows machine**

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

b = [21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30]


def combo(list_a,list_b):

   list_c = list_a + list_b

   combination = [(p,q,r,s) for p in list_c for q in list_c for r in list_c for s in list_c
                              if q > p and r > q and s > r]

   return(combination)


combo_ab = combo(a,b)

print(combo_ab)
```

**Exception has occurred: TypeError:**

**'>' not supported between instances of 'tuple' and 'int'**

** line 24 in  if q > p and r > q and s > r**

**line 25, in combo_4
combo_four = [(p,q,r,s) for p in list_c for q in list_c for r in list_c for s in list_c**

What seems to be the issue here?

Comment: Please post the full error traceback.

Comment: Please post which version of python you are using and the full error traceback

Comment: it's working fine on my windows machine